# Lockdown: insmod: unsigned module loading is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While inserting simple hello kernel module facing below error messge
Ex: insmod: ERROR: could not insert module main.ko: Operation not permitted
Os used:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/q/773734